# Reporting Services group with a condition

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

I have this source data :

[image: source data (image)]

First I want to group by "Name" (I already did this part), after this I want to create the"category" column, if a "Name" group have any row type1 = A, then the Category is "X" else category = "Z"

This is the result I want:

[image: result I need(image)]

How can I get the category group-column in reporting services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My defacto method for this would be to edit the SQL query feeding the report and add the logic to add the group there.  I assume that's not possible or you don't have access to the SQL layer, so here a way to do it completely in SSRS:

1. Insert another column to the right within your `Name` group
2. For the field expression, do a [lookupset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookupset-function) on the name field value and check if A exists in the results

   `=IIF(Array.IndexOf(Lookupset(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Type1.Value, "DatasetName"), A) > -1, "X", "Z")`

If you build the expression piece-meal, use the following expression to first check that your lookupset is working:

```
=JOIN(LookupSet(...), ",")
```

Then add the `IIF(Array.IndexOf(...,A) > -1, X, Z)` to see if the returned array contains your "A" value.